# PHP - Generate string that matches a pattern

Tags: php

I have the following issues:

- I have a pattern
- I need to generate a random(ish) string that matches that pattern

So far I generate random strings then match them against the pattern. This works, but may take a pretty long time for more complex patterns.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: can you please show us your pattern?

Comment: Since you know the pattern, you can build the parts with random substrings and then concat it to the string you are looking for.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a solution more "general" that does not depend on pattern (take this one for example: (\d{1,15}+(\.\d{1,4})?)( )?x( )?(\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?)( )?x( )?(\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?)(( )?-( )?(\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?))?( )).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the Reverse Parser:

https://github.com/icomefromthenet/ReverseRegex

```
$lexer = new  Lexer('[a-z]{10}');
$gen   = new SimpleRandom(10007);
$result = '';

$parser = new Parser($lexer,new Scope(),new Scope());
$parser->parse()->getResult()->generate($result,$gen);

echo $result;
```

produces this output:

```
jmceohykoa
aclohnotga
jqegzuklcv
ixdbpbgpkl
...
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, will take a better look at it.